# How to do + or - in php?

Tags: php

I want to have a form in following way:

```
[-] [value] [+]
```

I don't know how to script the logic to get the value 1 higher or 1 lower in PHP.

I assumed something like following would work:

```
<?php

$i = 0;

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    if(isset($_POST['plus']))
    {
        $i++;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['min']))
    {
        $i--;
    }
}

?>
```

and my form is as following:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="min" value="-"> <input type="text" value=<?php echo $i ?> >         <input type="submit" name="plus" value="+">
</form>
```

But I'm only getting either a 1 or a -1. Can someone show me how to do this in a good way?

Comment: The problem is that you reset $i to 0 every time it posts back to the server.  What you need is the post value from your textbox input.

Comment: The value of `$i` is set initially to `0` on each form submit.  You need to store `$i` in a session (or a database) for it to persist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php



if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $i = $_POST['current_value'] || 1;
    if(isset($_POST['plus']))
    {
        $i++;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['min']))
    {
        $i--;
    }
}
?>
```

and this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="min" value="-"> <input name="current_value" type="text" value=<?php echo $i ?> >         <input type="submit" name="plus" value="+">
</form>
```

You need some way to get the current value to persist between requests - depending on your use case, you may need database storage as Rocket mentions, or this simple passing back of the current value may be enough.

Comment: hmm is there no way with GET instead of POST to hold the value in the browser?

Answer (score 2):

PHP will simply load code on the server-side and run when the page is loaded. If you are looking to dynamically increment/decrement the value while remaining on the same page, I suggest you look into learning Javascript and jQuery.

**Reference**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/

**Reference**: http://jQuery.com/

Comment: can you help me with the jQuery part cause i am not very good at it.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening with your code is that you are incrementing a global variable that you set to 0 in the beginning.  That is why the only values you get back or 1 or -1.  This can be fixed by passing the variable you increment each time instead of using a global variable.  That way it keeps the value between each plus and minus and doesn't keep resetting it.

Comment: how do i pass it every time? do i have to use sessions?

Comment: Ya I used a session variable the last time I wanted to do something like this.

Comment: can you give me an example of how you did it?